# Gitlab-runner does not run command, normal shell does

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, rtrt

I'm trying to include a dynamic analysis of my source code using IBM RTRT and adding it to Gitlab CI.

I have read the manual and I can execute a full test suite using:

```
studio -r test_suite_group test_suiste_name.rtp -html ./html-folder
```

This runs properly on my normal cmd / Windows shell.

When I try to execute the same .bat on gitlab-runner, it does not execute and stuck on the first RTRT instruction.

Even when trying to execute the full (verbose) instruction test case per test case:

```
C:\IBM\TESTRE~2\bin\intel\win32\attolpreproC "x.ptu"      "y.c"      -studio_log="z.log" -STD_DEFINE="C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\TestRealTime\targets\cvisual6\ana\atus_c.def" -RENAME=stubs_rename.opt @RTRT/prepro.opt -family=nominal -service=TIUApiTimeoutFun -define="_RTRT_TEST_","ETCS","FLASH4M","ODO","CANTATA" -NOSIMULATION -COMPRESS -FAST
```

Gitlab-runner just becomes stuck at attolpreproC.

I am not able to troubleshoot this issue as it seems a shell / gitlab-runner shell problem. It seems that admin rights are given properly to gitlab-runner shell. Any other checks I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some RTRT exes were on "Compatibility Mode", it seems that Gitlab-Runner does not execute programs in this mode well even with admin rights. Removing the compatibility mode fixed the issue.